# Simile Timeline - Floating Dates

Tags: javascript, css, timeline, simile

We are trying to integrate the Simile Timeline (http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/) into a SalesForce.com powered page.

The business is, apartment bookings. The calendar will display the bookings against the related apartments. The apartments appear on a separate div on the left hand side and is fixed.

We may run into really long calendar (height > 1000px). What happens is, the date labels appear at the bottom of the page and are not visible when the user is at the top of the page.

[alt text http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/9459/grabsfcalendar.png](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/9459/grabsfcalendar.png)
(Note that, there are no bookings show in this grab nor is the height too high)

When the DAY band is too long to fit into the screen, the date markers are hidden. Would it be possible to float the dates (just in one band) so that even when the user scrolls (up or down), the dates are in still view?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but when you create a band in timeline, Timeline.createBandInfo() takes a parameters object, one of these parameters is 'align'. If you set this to "Top", then your date markers will appear at the top of the band. For example:

```
Timeline.createBandInfo({
    eventSource: eventSourceNarrative,
    date: "May 10 1199 00:00:00 GMT",
    width: "40%",  
    align: "Top",
    intervalUnit: Timeline.DateTime.MONTH,
    intervalPixels: 52,
    theme: johnTheme
}),
```

But note the proviso at http://www.simile-widgets.org/wiki/Timeline_ThemeClass#track

---

Alternatively, this property can be set in your 'theme' object instead using hAlign. see the docs at:

http://www.simile-widgets.org/wiki/Timeline_ThemeClass

---

See also the code at:
http://code.google.com/p/simile-widgets/source/browse/timeline/trunk/src/webapp/api/scripts/ether-painters.js

The function that actually applies the 'align' parameter is:

```
Timeline.EtherIntervalMarkerLayout
```

Comment: align: "top" works just as well as no value set. I need the date markers to always show - in some cases my band will be too tall to fit in my screen and the dates are hidden. I've edited the question to clarify this

Comment: I guess I'm still not clear on the question, and I'm not sure what '"top" works just as well as no value set' means. But how about this: you add a fourth band at the top synched with the band below it. This band would show only the date values, no events. Then you'll have the DAY scale both top and bottom. I don't think you can float them because the design strategy of timeline depends on all the elements plotted on the band having their positions calculated as absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a separate band with no data but is synced with the one that has data, that way, you will always be able to see the date? Most likely you need to turn on the vertical scrollbars to actually be within screen estate.

Comment: But this band too is going to go down if my first is very high. I don't need an answer to this any more professionally, but technically am very interested!